# Using Macport on OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, macports, xvfb

I installed macport following the guide.
http://afitnerd.com/2011/09/06/headless-browser-testing-on-mac/

However, when I try to run

```
sudo port upgrade
```

it has error message

```
Can't map the URL 'file://.' to a port description file ("Could not 
find Portfile in /Users").
Please verify that the directory and portfile syntax are correct.
To use the current port, you must be in a port's directory.
```

How should I switch to the right directory?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo port upgrade` tells MacPorts to upgrade the port defined by the `Portfile` in the current directory. It's usually a command only developers use while writing Portfiles. The guide likely meant `sudo port upgrade outdated` instead to upgrade all non-current ports. Since you don't have any ports installed if this is your first MacPorts installation, you can safely skip the command.

Note that `firefox-x11` has meanwhile been removed from MacPorts because it was broken, outdated, and nobody stepped up to maintain it.